# ProgressBar во всплывающем окне. Альтернативы ProgressDialog

Tags: android

Можно ли как-то отобразить `ProgressBar` во всплывающем окне (наподобие старого доброго `ProgressDialog`)?

Сам `ProgressDialog` не рассматриваю, т.к. начиная с API 26 он `deprecated`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373007/progressdialog-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternate-one-to-use

Comment: Зачем изобретать костыль, если гугл не рекомендует блокировать экран диалогом ?